# Simplify command in top

Tags: command-line, process, grep, top

I'm using the following command to gather the information of child-PID:

```
top -b -n1 -p 719011,719012,719013,719014,719015,719016,719017 | sed -e 's/USER/----/' -e 's/root/----/' -e 's/PR/--/' -e 's/20/--/' -e 's/VIRT/----/' -e 's/538m/----/' -e 's/RES/---/' -e 's/12m/---/' -e 's/SHR/---/' -e 's/1348/----/' -e 's/NI/--/' -e 's/S/-/' | tail -9 > file1
```

It works just fine, but is a little long winded! I want to know if there is anyway to gather the information just by using the pPID? Thus saving having to type every child process ID. I don't want the full answer just a pointer in the right direction so I can figure it out myself!

Okay, so I have tidied up the command to:

```
ps -o pid= --ppid 719008 | top -b -n4 | awk '{print $1,$9,$10,$12}' | tail -9 > file
```

But instead of giving the output for the child processes I get the output for every process on the system! What am I missing?

```
$ pstree -p 719008
dvaudio_server(719008)─┬─{dvaudio_server}(719011)
                       ├─{dvaudio_server}(719012)
                       ├─{dvaudio_server}(719013)
                       ├─{dvaudio_server}(719014)
                       ├─{dvaudio_server}(719015)
                       ├─{dvaudio_server}(719016)
                       └─{dvaudio_server}(719017)
```

And the output of `pgrep` is:

```
pgrep: option requires an argument -- 'd'
Usage: pgrep [-flvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST]
    [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]
```

Comment: `top` doesn't read PIDs from stdin. That's why I use `-p $(...)` in my answer.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I'm really very new to all this. if I,m understanding correctly the command should be thus : top -p $(pgrep -P 719008 -d,) | awk '{print $1,$9,$10,$12}' | tail -9 > file                                                            Or am I taking you to literally?

Comment: Yes, plus any additional options you want to give to `top`: `top -b -p $(pgrep -P 719008 -d,) -n4 | awk ....`

Comment: When I run top -p with -n4 after the pgrep the result is 'bad pid -n4' and without -n4 the result is '-p argument missing'

Comment: So, again: the output of the pgrep and pstree commands you executed, please.

Comment: @muru edited into question

Comment: you did use the `,` after `-d` right?

Comment: Sure did! It gives me reams of output including the 7 listed above. Just for the record, I really appreciate your help and patience on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the direct children of a process using [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pgrep.1.html):

```
-P, --parent ppid,...
      Only match processes whose parent process ID is listed.
```

And:

```
-d, --delimiter delimiter
      Sets  the  string  used to delimit each process ID in the output
      (by default a newline).  (pgrep only.)
```

So:

```
top ... -p $(pgrep -P <PPID> -d,) | ...
```

Comment: When I use pgrep along with the top command I get error bad pid? Driving me mad!!!!

Comment: @SimplySimplified run the pgrep command by itself to see what output it gives. Have you used the correct parent PID?

Comment: I get no output when running both pgrep and ps command you gave below. The ppid is correct, because when I run say a standard pstree -p PID it then brings up the process and it's tree!

Comment: @SimplySimplified which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm running 16.04

Comment: @SimplySimplified can you add the actual output you get from pstree and pgrep to the question?

Comment: Please see question box

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ps` to display a list of processes. It understands the `--ppid PPIDLIST` argument which allows you to filter the processes by a comma-separated list of parent process IDs.

From [`man ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps):

```
--ppid pidlist

Select by parent process ID. This selects the processes with a parent process ID in pidlist. 
That is, it selects processes that are children of those listed in pidlist.
```

So probably you should try something like

```
ps aux --ppid 12345
```

Comment: `ps -o pid= --ppid 12345`, more like